# C program not reading keyboard input

Tags: c, scanf, posix

EDIT: the problem is that scanf (and other function I tried here) doesn't wait for the input, the program doesn't pause.

Using Ubuntu 18 on Virtual Box on Mac
I am writing a server/client using POSIX. I am not able to read keyboard input in client.c

```
 char action_type[1];
    printf("Chose action: T to request time, S to shut down\n");
    scanf(" %c",action_type);
    printf("%s", action_type);
```

if I put the same code as the first thing in main.c it works fine.

full code for server / client and commons is:

server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mqueue.h"
#include "commons.h"
#include "errno.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>


int status_closing = 0;

void send_time(char* clients_pid);
void send_activation(char* clients_pid);


//VARIABLES related to SERVERS QUEUE

mqd_t server; // server


struct mq_attr servers_attributes; // server creation attributes

struct mq_attr receiving_attributes; // server receiving attributes

// set up attributes

void set_servers_attributes(){
    // set up server's attributes
    servers_attributes.mq_maxmsg = QUEUE_SIZE;
    servers_attributes.mq_msgsize = MESSAGE_SIZE;
    printf("attributes set \n");
};

// open server

void open_servers_queue() {

    server = mq_open (servers_path,
                      O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_EXCL ,
                      0666, &servers_attributes);


    if (server == -1) {
        printf("failed to open server's queue\n");
        printf(errno);
        exit(-1);
    } else {
        printf("opened servers queue as: %d\n",server);


    }
};

// check attributes

void check_attributes(){

    if ((mq_getattr(server,&receiving_attributes)) == -1) {

        printf("cannot read server's queue\n exit \n");
        exit(-1);
    }
};

void close_and_unlink_queue(){

    printf("At exit closing and unlinking queue\n");

    mq_close(server);
    mq_unlink(servers_path);

};

int check_for_messages_in_the_queue(){

    //printf("checking for messages\n");

    int messages_in_queue;
    messages_in_queue = receiving_attributes.mq_curmsgs;
    //printf("there are %d message in the servers queue\n",messages_in_queue);
   // printf("message in the queue!\n");
    return messages_in_queue;


};

char* receive_message(){

    char *receiving_buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*MESSAGE_SIZE);

    if ((mq_receive(server,receiving_buffer,MESSAGE_SIZE,NULL))>0){

        return receiving_buffer;
    }

    else {

        printf("Server failed to receive message");

        mq_close(server);
        mq_unlink(servers_path);

        exit(-1);


    }

};


void respond(char *message_type, char* clients_pid) {

    printf("responding\n");

    char* type_one = "1";
    char* type_two = "2";
    char *type_three ="3";

    if (strcmp(message_type, type_one) == 0) {

        printf("TYPE 1\n");

        send_activation(clients_pid);

    }

    if (strcmp(message_type, type_two) == 0) {

        printf("TYPE 2\n");

       send_time(clients_pid);


    }

    if (strcmp(message_type, type_three) == 0) {

        printf("type 3 - SHUTDOWN INITIATED\n");

    }

}

void send_time(char* clients_pid) {

    time_t mytime = time(NULL);
    char *time_str = ctime(&mytime);
    time_str[strlen(time_str)-1] = '\0';





    char *clientpath[20];
    int clients_pid_int = atoi(clients_pid);
    sprintf(clientpath,"/%d",clients_pid_int);
    printf("clients path: %s\n",clientpath);


    mqd_t  client;
    client = mq_open(clientpath,O_RDWR , 0666, &servers_attributes);

    if (client == -1) {
        printf("failes opening client's queue \n");
        exit(-1);
    } else {
        printf("connected to client's queue: %d\n",client);
    }



};


void send_activation(char* clients_pid) {

    char *clientpath[20];
    int clients_pid_int = atoi(clients_pid);
    sprintf(clientpath,"/%d",clients_pid_int);
    printf("clients path: %s\n",clientpath);


    mqd_t  client;
    client = mq_open(clientpath,O_RDWR , 0666, &servers_attributes);

    if (client == -1) {
        printf("failes opening client's queue \n");
        exit(-1);
    } else {
        printf("connected to client's queue: %d\n",client);
        char* activation = malloc(sizeof(char)*MESSAGE_SIZE);
        char* activation_literal = "activation";
        sprintf(activation,"%s",activation_literal);

        int message_sent = mq_send(client,activation,MESSAGE_SIZE,0);
        printf("message sent with: %d",message_sent);





    }
};


int main() {

    // clean remainings of previous trials

    mq_close(server);
    mq_unlink(servers_path);

    // define atexit behaviour

    atexit(close_and_unlink_queue);

    //set servers attributes:

    set_servers_attributes();

    // open server's queue

    open_servers_queue();

    // receiving messages in the loop

    int condition = 1;

    while (1) {

        check_attributes();

        if (check_for_messages_in_the_queue() > 0) {

            char *received_message = receive_message();

            char *tok_one = strtok(received_message," ");
            char *tok_two = strtok(NULL, " ");
            //int clients_pid = atoi(tok_two);

            respond(tok_one,tok_two);

        } else if ((check_for_messages_in_the_queue() ==0) && (status_closing == 1)) {

            printf("Server's queue is empty - work finished. closing down\n");
            exit(0);


        }

    }
        printf("Hello, World!\n");
        return 0;

}
```

client

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "commons.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

mqd_t client;
mqd_t server;
char clientpath[20];
char* sending_buffer[MESSAGE_SIZE];

struct mq_attr clients_attributes;

struct mq_attr receiving_attributes;

void connect_to_server(){

    server = mq_open(servers_path,O_WRONLY);
    if(server == -1) {
        printf("connection to server failed\n");

    } else {

        printf("connected to server with id: %d \n",server);
    }
};

void set_clients_attributes(){


    // deal with attributes

    clients_attributes.mq_maxmsg = QUEUE_SIZE;
    clients_attributes.mq_msgsize = MESSAGE_SIZE;

};







void create_clients_queue(){


    // create clients path
    pid_t client_pid = getpid();

    sprintf(clientpath, "/%d", client_pid);


    // open clients queue
    client = mq_open(clientpath,O_RDONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666, &clients_attributes);
   // printf(errno);

    if (client == -1) {
        printf("failes opening client's queue \n");
        exit(-1);
    } else {
        printf("connected to client's queue: %d\n",client);
    }
};

void register_at_server(){

    message message;
    message.mtype = 1;
    int client_pid = getpid();
    message.sender = client_pid;
    char separator = ' ';


    snprintf(sending_buffer,MESSAGE_SIZE,"%ld%c%d",message.mtype,separator,message.sender);


    if ((mq_send(server,sending_buffer, MESSAGE_SIZE,0)) == -1) {
        printf("failed to send registration request\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    else {

        printf("%s",sending_buffer);
        printf("sent registration request\n");


    }

};

void close_and_unlink_queue(){

    printf("At exit closing and unlinking queue\n");

    mq_close(client);
    mq_unlink(clientpath);

};


void check_attributes(){

    if ((mq_getattr(client,&receiving_attributes)) == -1) {

        printf("cannot read own's queue\n exit \n");
        exit(-1);
    }
};

int check_for_messages_in_the_queue(){

    //printf("checking for messages\n");

    int messages_in_queue;
    messages_in_queue = receiving_attributes.mq_curmsgs;
    //printf("there are %d message in the servers queue\n",messages_in_queue);
    // printf("message in the queue!\n");
    return messages_in_queue;


};

char* receive_message(){

    char *receiving_buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*MESSAGE_SIZE);

    if ((mq_receive(client,receiving_buffer,MESSAGE_SIZE,NULL))>0){

        return receiving_buffer;
    }

    else {

        printf("Server failed to receive message");

        mq_close(client);
        mq_unlink(clientpath);

        exit(-1);


    }

};



void choose_action(){

    char action_type[1];
    printf("Chose action: T to request time, S to shut down\n");
    scanf(" %c",action_type);
    printf("%s", action_type);











};





int main() {

    mq_close(client);
    mq_unlink(clientpath);

    connect_to_server();

    set_clients_attributes();

    create_clients_queue();

    register_at_server();

    int condition = 1;
    int client_active = 0;

    while (condition) {

        check_attributes();

        if (check_for_messages_in_the_queue() > 0) {
            char *received_message = receive_message();
            if ((strcmp(received_message, "activation")) == 0) {
                client_active = 1;
                condition = 0;
                free(received_message);
            }
        }
    }

    char action_type[1];
    printf("Chose action: T to request time, S to shut down\n");
    scanf(" %c",action_type);
    printf("%s", action_type);









    printf("Hello, World!\n");
        return 0;

}
```

commons

```
#ifndef SERVER_COMMONS_H
#define SERVER_COMMONS_H

#include <signal.h>

// define values of server queue attributes

//define message struct

typedef struct messgae {
    char content[4096];
    pid_t sender;
    long mtype;

} message;



#define QUEUE_SIZE 10
#define MESSAGE_SIZE sizeof(message)

// define servers path
const char servers_path[] = "/server";






#endif //SERVER_COMMONS_H
``
```

Comment: The problem seems to be in the client program, so you don't need to show the server program. Also please keep in mind the ***minimal*** part of your [mcve].

Comment: By the way you know that the `printf` format specifier `%s` is for *null-terminated strings*? Your array `action_type` only holds a single character and can thus *never* be a null-terminated string. Attempting to use it as such will go out of bounds and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Change `scanf(" %c",action_type);` to `scanf("%c",&action_type[0]); printf("%c", action_type);` BTW, why not take a single character instead of an array?

Comment: "`scanf` ... doesn't wait for the input" -- show examples of actual input, actual output, and expected output to clarify the problem.

Comment: @Siddharth -- why change `" %c"` to `"%c"`? That would only worsen the problem; the space in the format string tells `scanf()` to discard any leading whitespace characters, e.g., any newlines left in the input stream from previous inputs. Also, `&action_type[0]` is equivalent to `action_type` in this context since arrays decay to pointers to their first elements (in most cases, but certainly here). Also, `printf("%c", action_type)` causes undefined behavior since `action_type` decays to a pointer to `char`, and this is a type mismatch for `%c` which expects a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

this happens because the buffer is not empty and this function read from it.
to empty buffer just try this code:

```
while( getchar() != '\n');
```

it will empty the buffer and after it the functions will wait for input.

Comment: I tried flushing the buffer before with the same code - it doesn't work - it keeps flushing forever. My guess it one of the functions called in main has side effects which are filling the buffer, or it's a VM related

Comment: The idiomatic way to do this is `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);`. This avoids a potential infinite loop since `getchar()` can return `EOF`; `c` must be an `int` since `EOF` may not be in the range of `char` (and `getchar()` returns an `int`).

Answer (score 0):

```
printf( "Enter a value :");
   c = getchar( );
```

or

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( ) {

   char str[100];
   int i;

   printf( "Enter a value :");
   scanf("%s %d", str, &i);

   printf( "\nYou entered: %s %d ", str, i);

   return 0;
}
```